# Mono Cecil loading the a modified assembly

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I would like to know if it is possible to load an assembly dynamically after modifying it with Mono.Cecil

Usually, I load my assemblies this way. It requires to save the assembly to a file.

```
Assembly assembly Assembly.LoadFile(path);
if (assembly != null)
{
    foreach (ISomething thing in FindInterfaces<ISomething>(assembly))
    {
        loadedThings.Add(thing);
        thing.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar from an AssemblyDefinition or a ModuleDefinition, without having to write it to a file?

Edit :

I ended up using a MemoryStream for now. If someone have an alternative I am all ears :)